# I have not found shp2pgsql in postgis installation

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ubuntu, shp2pgsql

I have been installed postgis following [this guide](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt). All is OK.

```
SELECT postgis_full_version();
"POSTGIS="2.1.7 r13414" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER"
```

But I have not the shp2pgsql  in `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin` as you can see:

```
foo@bar:/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin$ ls
clusterdb   initdb             pg_dump         pg_standby      psql
createdb    oid2name           pg_dumpall      pg_test_fsync   reindexdb
createlang  pg_archivecleanup  pg_isready      pg_test_timing  vacuumdb
createuser  pg_basebackup      pg_receivexlog  pg_upgrade      vacuumlo
dropdb      pgbench            pg_recvlogical  pg_xlogdump
droplang    pg_controldata     pg_resetxlog    postgres
dropuser    pg_ctl             pg_restore      postmaster
```

Why this happens? and how can I install it?

Comment: Not sure about linux but on Windows shp2pgsql is in with the PostGis\bin and not postgresql\bin..

Answer (score 21):

I was also following the OP's installation [method](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt) of PostgreSQL and PostGIS, namely

`sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1 pgadmin3 postgresql-contrib-9.4`

I enabled the PostGIS extension in a database but didn't get `shp2pgsql` to work until I did

`sudo apt-get install postgis`

as listed toward the bottom of the page. Why `postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1` doesn't include `shp2pgsql` and simply `postgis` does .... I'm not really sure. But PostgreSQL, PostGIS, and `shp2pgsql` are all working fine now.

Comment: Same goes for Fedora

Answer (score 9):

When installing postgis on Linux, be sure to install the client also, as postgis on its own will not install the shp2pgsql executable.

```
yum install postgis2_94
yum install postgis2_94-utils
yum install postgis2_94-client
```

Until you install the client, there is just a link in /usr/bin/ pointing to /etc/alternatives/postgis-shp2pgsql. This is just an empty link until the client install places the executables in /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin.

Hope this helps, appreciate the OP asked the question some months ago and I hope found a resolution sooner.

Comment: Updating in 2023... working with RHEL 9.2, postgresql15, and postgis 3.3.3. Installing the utils and client worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, the `shp2pgsql` binary is in `/usr/bin/shp2pgsql` when you install with packages like in the method you mentioned.

Did you type `shp2pgsql` in command line? Normally, it works out of the box.

If not,

- did you do an `updatedb` (command line to index files) followed with a `locate shp2pgsql` to find the real binary path?
- did you echoed the output from the command line using `echo $PATH`? And what is the output?

Comment: Command `sudo locate shp2pgsql` is empty. Command `echo $PAHT` returns `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Comment: Because `sudo locate shp2pgsql` is empty, it seems you didn't installed `shp2pgsql` properly (or you forgot to do `sudo updatedb`).

If the package name is the same for additional repo and the default, doing a `sudo apt-get install postgis` should install both `shp2pgsql` and `shp2pgsql-gui`.

This answer is based on the fact I supposed you are using a Debian based distro (Debian, Mint or Ubuntu)

Comment: I run `sudo shp2pgsql` and `sudo apt-get install postgis` but keeps the error `foo@bar:/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4$ shp2pgsql
bash: /usr/local/bin/shp2pgsql: No existe el archivo o el directorio`

Answer (score 1):

This is more difficult than expected when going against the grain of the latest releases, which is possible using the `http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt`.

For example, when using postgresql-11 installations, simply adding postgis attempts to also add postgresql-12 !

```
$ dpkg -l | grep postg
ii  pgdg-keyring                               2018.2                                                     all          keyring for apt.postgresql.org
ii  postgis-doc                                2.4.3+dfsg-4                                               all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL -- documentation
ii  postgresql-11                              11.7-2.pgdg18.04+1                                         amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 11 server
ii  postgresql-11-pgrouting                    3.0.0~rc1-1.pgdg18.04+1                                    amd64        Routing functionality support for PostgreSQL/PostGIS
ii  postgresql-11-pgrouting-scripts            3.0.0~rc1-1.pgdg18.04+1                                    all          Routing functionality support for PostgreSQL/PostGIS - SQL scripts
ii  postgresql-11-postgis-2.5                  2.5.4+dfsg-1.pgdg18.04+1                                   amd64        Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 11
ii  postgresql-11-postgis-2.5-scripts          2.5.4+dfsg-1.pgdg18.04+1                                   all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 11 -- SQL scripts
ii  postgresql-client-11                       11.7-2.pgdg18.04+1                                         amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 11
ii  postgresql-client-common                   213.pgdg18.04+1                                            all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common                          213.pgdg18.04+1                                            all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
ii  postgresql-plpython-11                     11.7-2.pgdg18.04+1                                         amd64        PL/Python procedural language for PostgreSQL 11
ii  postgresql-plpython3-11                    11.7-2.pgdg18.04+1                                         amd64        PL/Python 3 procedural language for PostgreSQL 11
ii  postgresql-server-dev-11                   11.7-2.pgdg18.04+1                                         amd64        development files for PostgreSQL 11 server-side programming


$ sudo apt-get install  postgis
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  postgresql-12 postgresql-12-postgis-3 postgresql-12-postgis-3-scripts postgresql-client-12
Suggested packages:
  postgis-gui postgresql-doc-12
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  postgis postgresql-12 postgresql-12-postgis-3 postgresql-12-postgis-3-scripts postgresql-client-12
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Need to get 336 kB/20.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 90.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

There is no option for a postgis-11 set of utils.   If everything else is on the latest versions, it just-works.

Trying to install only the postgis package sorta works, but it installs a 3.x version rather than a matching 2.x version, e.g.

```
$ sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends postgis
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  postgis-gui
Recommended packages:
  postgresql-12-postgis-3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  postgis
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
Need to get 336 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,621 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg/main amd64 postgis amd64 3.0.1+dfsg-2.pgdg18.04+1 [336 kB]
Fetched 336 kB in 2s (215 kB/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package postgis.
(Reading database ... 374551 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../postgis_3.0.1+dfsg-2.pgdg18.04+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking postgis (3.0.1+dfsg-2.pgdg18.04+1) ...
Setting up postgis (3.0.1+dfsg-2.pgdg18.04+1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating first, and then proceed from there:

`sudo apt-get update`.

Seems dumb, but I was having trouble with my installations of psql and postgis and it all cleared up once I updated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some news on it. With `APT`, PostgreSQL 13 and PostGIS 3 you will need to also install `apt install postgis-gui`.

Source: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/postgis-gui_3.0.0+dfsg-6ubuntu4_amd64.deb.html

Or p.570 of PostGIS in Action 3ed.