# shp2pgsql-gui not work after Ubuntu update

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with postgres-9.5 and postgis 2.2.2.

Previously I performed `shp2pgsql-gui` to access the interface, but now, the terminal shows me this message:

```
the program shp2pgsql-gui not installed in the moment. you can install
typing sudo-apt-get install postgis
```

The result of:

```
select * from postGIS_full_version()
```

is:

```
POSTGIS="2.2.2 r14797" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.11.99" TOPOLOGY RASTER
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: try the answers here  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148524/i-have-not-found-shp2pgsql-in-postgis-installation

Comment: @kttii I had ever seen, but it did not work

Comment: so you ran 'sudo apt-get install postgis' after the error you described above?  did it produce any errors?

Comment: did you try 'sudo locate shp2pgsql' and was there any result?

Comment: please edit/update the question with your results after you try something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that 'shp2pgsql-gui' is now part of the postgis-gui package

Try :
`sudo apt-get install postgis-gui`

It worked for me.